# Using emojis via text message in Java

Tags: java, sms, emoji, vonage

I've been trying to using emojis in the code for about an hour with no success. The emoji displays successfully on the console but as soon as I send myself a text message, everything breaks and this happens.
[Emoji fails to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkSHA.png)

Here is my code right now, not sure what to do, any help would be appreciated:

```
SmsSubmissionResult[] response = 
client.getSmsClient().submitMessage(new TextMessage(
                "REMOVED",
                "REMOVED",
                "**\ud83d\ude36** Homework Task Due (18th December 
2017)\n**\ud83d\ude3c** For English: Revise for end of term 
test\n**\ud83d\ude47** This will take approximately 1 hour.\n\n"));
```

Comment: Please tag appropriately to indicate which API you're using. It appears to be nexmo, on the basis of `SmsSubmissionResult[]`; but it's helpful if you can actually state it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be sending the message using [this constructor of `TextMessage`](https://nexmo.github.io/nexmo-java/com/nexmo/client/sms/messages/TextMessage.html#TextMessage-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

```
TextMessage(String from, String to, String messageBody)
```

Use [the one with is `unicode` flag](https://nexmo.github.io/nexmo-java/com/nexmo/client/sms/messages/TextMessage.html#TextMessage-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-boolean-), set it to `true`:

```
 TextMessage(String from, String to, String messageBody, boolean unicode)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response - I saw this but forgot to say thanks!

Comment: @JoeStevens you're welcome; but if this answers your question, please consider accepting it (the tick on the left).